# Bind Odata call to data grid view in a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, api, odata

I'm wondering if this is possible at all, but here is this public odata webservice: http://services.odata.org/AdventureWorksV3/AdventureWorks.svc/

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the data from this webservice and bind it to a datagrid view. I was able to get it to a textbox using this code:

```
public void DisplayProduct(AdventureWorksService.vProductCatalog product)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + product.ProductName + " | " + product.ProductNumber + " | " + product.ProductCategory + Environment.NewLine);
}

public void ListAllProducts(AdventureWorksService.AdventureWorksEntities container)
{
    foreach (var p in container.ProductCatalog)
    {
        DisplayProduct(p);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://services.odata.org/AdventureWorksV3/AdventureWorks.svc/");
    var container = new AdventureWorksService.AdventureWorksEntities(uri);

    container.SendingRequest2 += (s, a) =>
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(a.RequestMessage.Method + " " + a.RequestMessage.Url);

    };

    ListAllProducts(container);
}
```

I tried merging the`AdventureWorksService.vProductCatalog` product to a dataset but that didn't work.